# qr-js npm package not installing

Tags: node.js, qr-code

I am installing qr-js npm package into my project and somehow i abled to install it after changing node version from v0.11.14-pre to 0.10.25. but starting my project it gives error.
I am new to node and don't know how to solve it.

error is-

"stack": [
    "Error: Module did not self-register.",
    "    at Error (native)",
    "    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)",
    "    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)",
    "    at require (module.js:384:17)",
    "    at Object. (/home/oodles/work/125fortime/125forTime/125ForTime-Server/EventManagement/node_modules/qr-js/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:2:18)",
    "    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)",
    "    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)",
    "    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)",
    "    at require (module.js:384:17)",
    "    at Object. (/home/oodles/work/125fortime/125forTime/125ForTime-Server/EventManagement/node_modules/qr-js/node_modules/canvas/lib/canvas.js:12:14)",
    "    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)",
    "    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)",
    "    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)",
    "    at require (module.js:384:17)",
    "    at /home/oodles/work/125fortime/125forTime/125ForTime-Server/EventManagement/node_modules/qr-js/qr.js:1201:14",
    "    at Object. (/home/oodles/work/125fortime/125forTime/125ForTime-Server/EventManagement/node_modules/qr-js/qr.js:1217:3)",
    "    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)"
  ],
  "level": "error",
  "message": "uncaughtException: Module did not self-register."
}
{
  "level": "info",
  "message": "Connected to mongo server."
}

Can anybody help..[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `npm rebuild` before running, and don't use `sudo` to install dependencies

Comment: I did, but no difference, still throwing same error after running

Comment: Delete `node_modules` then run `npm install`, can you show us the `package.json` file

Comment: already tried but no result.

Comment: I have attached the package.json file image with question.

Comment: I was running project with "node app.js" which was thowing error but when i tried with "nodejs app.js" it worked. but I am not able to understand what was the problem with node command, earlier it was working fine..